# Why onTouchEvent of SurfaceView called a few seconds delayed?

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event, s5

I have a very simple game SurfaceView  and sometimes game does not responde to touch events for a few seconds, then it respondes to the all of those touch events at once. I have tested my game on Galaxy S3 and Nexus 4 and it works fine, it seems this problem only occurs on Galaxy S5.

1. Main Activity:

   ```
   public class DroidzActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private static final String TAG = DroidzActivity.class.getSimpleName();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // requesting to turn the title OFF
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       // making it full screen
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       // set our MainGamePanel as the View
       setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));
       Log.d(TAG, "View added");
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
       super.onDestroy();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
       super.onStop();
   }     

   }
   ```

   2. MainGamePanel

public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

private MainThread thread;

public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");
}

public void render(Canvas canvas){
    if(canvas!=null)
        canvas.drawColor(colorList[colorIndex]);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        colorIndex++;
        colorIndex = colorIndex % colorList.length;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
int [] colorList = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.GRAY};
    int colorIndex = 0;

}
```

3. MainThread

   public class MainThread extends Thread {

   ```
   private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

   // Surface holder that can access the physical surface
   private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
   // The actual view that handles inputs
   // and draws to the surface
   private MainGamePanel gamePanel;

   // flag to hold game state 
   private boolean running;
   public void setRunning(boolean running) {
       this.running = running;
   }

   public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
       super();
       this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
       this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
   }


   // desired fps
   private final static int    MAX_FPS = 50;   
   // maximum number of frames to be skipped
   private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;    
   // the frame period
   private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;  


   @Override
   public void run() {
       Canvas canvas;
       Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");

       long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
       long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
       int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
       int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 

       sleepTime = 0;

       while (running) {
           canvas = null;
           // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
           // in the surface
           try {
               canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
               synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                   beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                   framesSkipped = 0;  // resetting the frames skipped
                   // update game state 
               //  this.gamePanel.update();
                   // render state to the screen
                   // draws the canvas on the panel
                   this.gamePanel.render(canvas);              
                   // calculate how long did the cycle take
                   timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                   // calculate sleep time
                   sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                   if (sleepTime > 0) {
                       // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                       try {
                           // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                           // very useful for battery saving
                           Thread.sleep(sleepTime);    
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                   }

                   while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                       // we need to catch up
                       // update without rendering
                   //  this.gamePanel.update(); 
                       // add frame period to check if in next frame
                       sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  
                       framesSkipped++;
                   }
               }
           } finally {
               // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
               // an inconsistent state
               if (canvas != null) {
                   surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
               }
           }   // end finally
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Here is the most simple version of the app, I have tried and I have able to recreate same problem again. It also sometimes takes 5-10 seconds to load on S5 while it loads less then 1 second on Nexus 4 and S3.

Comment: code please, we are not mighty oracles :)

Comment: Initial guess would be that the events are arriving in the application, but either the UI thread is stalled, or the thread that handles the input events (SurfaceView render thread?) is failing to process them in a timely manner.

Comment: Might be related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/13254824/1531054

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like MainThread is starving the UI thread.

The code that ends up executing (with a lot of stuff removed) looks like:

```
canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
// Do a ton of stuff
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
// Do a ton of stuff
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
// Do a ton of stuff
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

This is supported by the android source.  Note that `SurfaceHolder#lock` calls [`mSurfaceLock.lock()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/view/SurfaceView.java#753).  This is also called in [`SurfaceHolder#updateWindow`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/view/SurfaceView.java#489), which is called in a variety of other places in that file.

`mSurfaceLock` is a [`ReentrantLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), and the documentation states:

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting  thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any
>   particular access order.

SurfaceView doesn't specify fairness, so it should be using the default, which can lead to exactly this starvation.

Try moving some of your work and particularly the sleeps outside the lock/unlock calls.

Comment: This might also be the cause of slowness on the S5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really solved my mysterious problem. By the way, even google's sample LunarLander has the same mistake.