# Load on Threads is Locking Up GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcplistener

My application is a communications server that receives TCP messages from a web server and then re-broadcasts the message to a number of iPads. It's a windows forms application in C#. Program.cs creates an instance of the primary form and then that form creates four threads that do the communications work. There is a thread that listens for messages from the web server, a thread that processes the incoming messages into the data that needs to be transmitted and a thread that handles sending the outbound messages. The fourth thread does database cleanup and spends 99% of it's time sleeping.

The problem I'm seeing is the GUI locks up with a load is placed on the system. On incoming message may represent 50 or 100 outgoing messages. While testing I'm restricting they system to only send 5 messages out at a time, so it requires a longer transmission time. The sending process is using async call backs, but even it it wasn't, I can't understand why load on the tread could be stalling the GUI thread.

I'm removed a much of the cross thread communications from the thread to the GUI for status update. The pattern for communications to the GUI is:

```
public void StatusOutput(string myString)
{
    if (this.lbStatus.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.lbStatus.BeginInvoke(new DebugOutputInvoker(StatusOutput), myString);
    }
    else
    {
        lbStatus.Items.Add(myString);
        while (lbStatus.Items.Count >= 501)
        {
            lbStatus.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        lbStatus.SelectedItem = lbStatus.Items.Count - 1;
}    // StatusUpdate() ...
```

Can anyone give me any advice on how to pursue this? I though threads were completely isolated from the GUI and couldn't load it.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254824/when-the-worker-thread-works-ui-becomes-choppy

Comment: A common way to get an unresponsive UI is to do a great deal of work on the UI thread thus tying up the UI thread so it can't service other UI events.   Speculating wildly on the limited information available, is it possible that - under load - your `lbStatus.Items.Count` grows so large that the `while` loop never exits?  For example if `Count` > 501 and other threads add to `lbStatus.Items` more quickly than the UI thread can loop on `RemoveAt`?

Comment: Interesting thought! Maybe I should setup a queue for the status display and then have the UI thread update the display it's self from messages in the queue, then only one thread is writing to the GUI object.

Comment: My earlier comment was a bit rubbish.  Thinking about this some more it looks like you're using `BeginInvoke` to run `StatusOutput` on the UI thread so (perhaps?) the only thread that ever adds to `lbStatus.Items` is the UI thread.  To some extent I'm guessing since we don't know the types of `this` and `lbStatus`.  You might think about [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.  If you're lucky that example will let you solve the problem yourself and at worst you'll improve your chances of someone else helping.

Comment: lbStatus is gonna be a ListBox, ask any Hungarian:)

Comment: Martin you are a good linguist! Frank, StatusOutput gets called mostly by the threads when they need to display information. So I'll try a cut that off and see if that stops the loading.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I removed all thread to GUI communications and the GUI stopped locking up. So this proved it wasn't a GUI thread issue. I work through the threads till I found out it's the TCPSender thread that has a lot of async callback functions, potentially hundreds of them. When ever this thread get's busy with it's async calls, the GUI locks up. I suspect it has to do with call backs happening while the thread has one of the GUI's methods in process.

I've solved the issue with making a new thread that just collects data from the operational threads and then updates the user interface. General status message that were transferred to the status display on the GUI thread are now queued and updated to the GUI through this new thread.

The GUI remains responsive and actually seems to be able to display more data now.